# SSL/443 port showing as closed -- Webserver Setup; Apache/Namecheap/DynamicDNS

Tags: linux, networking, apache-http-server, ssl, raspberry-pi

I am facing a problem with my SSL/443 port. I setup a website which is currently being hosted on Apache, port 80. I do have an SSL certificate and was able to redirect HTTP to HTTPS -- but after a while port 443 stops responding to requests and I have to revert back to using port 80. Somehow 443/HTTPS works for little bit and then stops working.

On the modem (Actiontec C2100T - CenturyLink) - I have both port 80 and 443 open. However when I check online if 443 is open, I get the following: Error: I could not see your service on 97.118.xx.xx. on port (443)

On the webserver (RasberryPi) - I ran an nmap scan:

```
Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-02-08 17:50 UTC
Nmap scan report for Unknown.domain (192.168.0.30)
Host is up (0.000051s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE   VERSION
22/tcp  open  ssh       (protocol 2.0)
80/tcp  open  http      Apache httpd 2.4.25 ((Raspbian))
85/tcp  open  http      Apache httpd 2.4.25 ((Raspbian))
443/tcp open  ssl/https Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian)
```

So I don't think it's the server -- but I could be wrong. Here is my Apache config as well. I've commented out VirtualHost 443 for now until I can figure out why the port becomes inactive after being initially configured.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blissisit.com
    #ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias www.blissisit.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    #Redirect permanent / https://blissisit.com/
    #Redirect permanent / https://192.168.0.30/
</VirtualHost>

#<VirtualHost *:443>
   #ServerName      blissisit.com
   #ServerAlias     www.blissisit.com
   #DocumentRoot    /var/www/html
   #SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/blissisit_com.crt
   #SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/ssl/private/blissisit.key
   #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/blissisit_com.ca-bundle
   #SSLEngine On

   #ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   #CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
#</VirtualHost>
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Was this tested both internally and external?

Comment: Can you define the parameters of how you would test both internally and externally?

Comment: You may want to explain your network set up.  Do you have a firewall/router in place and is the server behind it?

Comment: Understood. Network wise -- I have a router an Actiontec C2100T from CenturyLink (basically a unit they provided as part of signing up with them). The firewall is disabled on the router. I've port forwarded port 443 and 80. The RasberryPi sits behind the router. There isn't anything special about the network at all. One router and the server plugs into it directly via Ethernet.

Comment: So when it fails to connect, have you tried both the local IP and the public IP?  Basically I want to eliminate the router as a potential problem.  Also have you checked the apache logs?

Comment: From a local IP standpoint, things work as they should. I am able to get to the site by typing https://blissisit.com (with or without the www) and it resolves internally. Locally, I can type 192.168.0.25 and get to the server, same with entering https://192.168.0.25 (but that's if I uncomment the 443 VirtualHost seen above). Publically however, it's a different story. Port 80 works as it should, but even when I enable and configure 443 in Apache as a VirtualHost, everything looks like it will work, but when I try connecting to my website via 443 or HTTPS, I get the error: "Connection refused".

Comment: Also, logs (access.log and error.log) don't show much besides proper connections being made to port 80. I get the 200 code which is good. But there is nothing in the logs speaking to SSL/HTTPS.

Comment: One more thing - what does loopback from the server result in when 443 fails externally?  I would say that if it works fine locally/internally then that points to a problem with the modem/router.  Did you set up port triggering or a static forwarding rule?   Second, was this equipment provided by the ISP?  If so it may be possible they're messing/limiting functionality, or maybe its just a crappy/dying device. (Many ISPs don't want you running servers, but not sure if that is relevant here.)

Comment: I can confirm that going to http:// 192.168.0.25 and https:// 192.168.0.25 work perfectly fine. So internally, it does look like everything is functioning properly. I would agree with your assessment that the modem/router might be the problem. I did add a rule in the modem/router for both port 80 and 443. But I will remove the 443 rule and add it again. And yes, the equipment was provided by the ISP - so they very well could be limiting the functionality in some way.

Comment: Got it figured out. Had to reset the port forwarding rules in the router and then have the DNS propagate again. Thanks for your help!

Comment: For the sake of completeness I'll submit an answer with this information

Answer (score 0):

Understanding the network topology goes a long way with nailing down these problems.

Is this server exposed to the internet (e.g. in the DMZ) or is in on a private network with ports forwarded?  If the latter, when the server fails to respond, is it failing both externally and internally (e.g. with the servers local private IP)?
Confirm by testing both scenarios.  Furthermore you can check the local loopback from the server.

Server logs can help as well.  For apache these will be access.log and error.log.  Location may vary by distro but generally located in var/log/apache/ or /var/log/apache2/ or /var/log/httpd/

Finally, you can try removing and re-adding the forwards, and possibly rebooting the modem/firewall.  Also note that some ISPs do some trickery with their provided equipment as they may wish to deter non-business accounts from running servers.